How can I bypass the defaults set by Jsonnet templating?
I am trying to generate a kubernetes manifest using Jsonnet and I want to completely remove deployment.spec.replicas field. But, when the manifest is generated, Jsonnet is applying it default replica count of 1 to the generated manifest. Is there a way to bypass the default value?
Removed the replicas field from my jsonnet file and I was expecting to see no replicas set in my deployment manifest. Instead I am currently seeing replicas:1
A minimal version of my jsonnet code:
      'app-deployment':
        deployment.new(
          name=app,
          containers=[
            container1,
            container2,
          ],
        )

The above template translated to the following manifest with replica set to 1:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: ns
spec:
  replicas: 1


Please include a minimal repro of your issue so that we may help

@DazWilkin I have added a brief snippet of my code and the generated manifest

Thanks! I assume this is deployment.new or similar.  This function is defaulting replicas=1 and it provides no mechanism by which the field can be omitted. You would need to duplicate the functionality to produce a mechanism that did not include it in the generated JSON. However when you apply this to a cluster, the cluster is going to add the field back with the default value see Deployment

Thanks @DazWilkin. So, I guess there is really no way to ignore the defaults. I am setting a minimum replica count via autoscaler and this is messing with it.

Interesting. I read the HPA docs and these do indeed suggest deleting spec.replicas from Deployments and manifests. I don't understand how the manifests won't be defaulted when recreated but... I think you'll want to try copying the source to deployment.new and removing the spec.replicas field.

Have are you generating those manifest?

@DawidKruk using Tanka

1st: would have really appreciated a full, working source code sample, similar to the one I provide below.
You can remove any field from being manifested in the resulting JSON by using the :: assignment like:
   replicas:: null, // can be any value really

Full example provided below:
deploy.jsonnet sample code
local k = (import 'vendor/k8s-libsonnet/1.28/main.libsonnet');
local deployment = k.apps.v1.deployment;
local container = k.core.v1.container;

local deployNoReplica(name, containers) = deployment.new(name=name, containers=containers) {
  spec+: {
    replicas:: null,
  },
};

{
  'app-deployment':
    deployNoReplica(
      name='app',
      containers=[
        container.new(name='container1', image='image1'),
        container.new(name='container2', image='image2'),
      ],
    ),
}

output
Note: using jsonnet-bundler to setup the local needed libs.
$ jb init
$ jb install github.com/jsonnet-libs/k8s-libsonnet/1.28@main
$ jsonnet deploy.jsonnet
{
   "app-deployment": {
      "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
      "kind": "Deployment",
      "metadata": {
         "name": "app"
      },
      "spec": {
         "selector": {
            "matchLabels": {
               "name": "app"
            }
         },
         "template": {
            "metadata": {
               "labels": {
                  "name": "app"
               }
            },
            "spec": {
               "containers": [
                  {
                     "image": "image1",
                     "name": "container1"
                  },
                  {
                     "image": "image2",
                     "name": "container2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}



This is giving me an output of replicas: null in the generated manifest

This is likely because there's another object referring to the replicas field of the Deployment. You'll really need to provide a fully reproducible example.
